# How to disable dev tools in atom editor

Tags: atom-editor

There is a feature in atom editor to show dev tools when you double-click on a word. Probably it is intended for html, but in ruby code it is not working. When you double-click on a specific word it is activating dev tools, opens console and show some error.

How can I disable it? I didn't find a setting and am not sure if this comes with an installed plugin.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The developer tools aren't opening as a feature: they're opening because there's an error somewhere! Unfortunately, Chromium (on top of which Atom is built) doesn't show a full stacktrace unless the dev tools are open *before* the exception is raised.

Try opening them yourself first with *View -> Developer -> Toggle Developer Tools* (or running the `Window: Toggle Dev Tools` command from the palette) and try to reproduce the problem by double-clicking on the word again. You should see a full stacktrace now, hopefully including an indication of the package that's causing the problem.

Comment: So it is true: If you want to debug your editor instead your code, use atom. Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 2):

Good answer by Ash Wilson, but I wanted to point out a handy package to disable the dev console from opening when there is an error: https://atom.io/packages/error-status .

You should find out what is causing the error, however most of the time it is annoying.  This package shows the error right above the status bar.  So you can still click it to see what the error is, but it is less obtrusive than opening the console.

**Edit**: [Package was removed](https://github.com/postcasio/error-status/issues/13).  Atom now has better error handling and a notification shows instead.

Comment: Looks like the package was removed?

Comment: This package was removed because it was using [deprecated functions](https://github.com/postcasio/error-status/issues/13) and no longer worked.  However, it is no longer needed because Atom has better error handling and a notification shows instead.